# click only on element postition in top right of image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to overlay a font icon in the top right corner of some images.
I only want an event fired when I click the icon but as I have it currently, the entire image will trigger the click.
What is a better way to structure this so I could accomplish the above?

```
<div class="col-3">
    <h5>Dashboard Background</h5>
    <div class="image">
        <div class="icon-image-delete">
            <img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="@Url.Action("Render", "Image", new { type = PreferenceImageType.DashboardBackground })" alt="No Background" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.icon-image-delete {
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

.icon-image-delete:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: '\f014';
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    color: #ff0000;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative positioning of icon and image: https://jsfiddle.net/jthy3q0o/2/

#### HTML

```
<div class="col-3">
    <h5>Dashboard Background</h5>
    <div class="image">
        <span class="icon-image-delete"></span>
        <img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="https://1.img-dpreview.com/files/p/TC190x190S190x190~sample_galleries/9912837935/2779432071.jpg" alt="No Background" />
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 190px;
  height:190px;
}

.icon-image-delete:before {
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f014";
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    right: 0;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    color: #ff0000;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you are so close to get it. Add the following to `.icon-image-delete:after`

```
text-align: center;
top: 0;
```

`text-align: center` to center the icon

`top: 0;` so it is on top (you have `right:0` so it positioned top right)

```css
.icon-image-delete {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.icon-image-delete:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f014';
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  color: #ff0000;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-3">
  <h5>Dashboard Background</h5>
  <div class="image">
    <div class="icon-image-delete">
      <img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/550x450" alt="No Background" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```